# When/What/Why/How to use value of UIApplicationOptionsURLKey from launchOptions in application(application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, appdelegate, uiapplicationdelegate

*BACKGROUND*

I have just begun to learn Apple's API, and right now, I'm learning about the functions of `UIApplicationDelegate`.
More specifically, I'm dissecting `func application(application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool`.

---

*QUESTIONS*

A key that can be found in `launchOptions` is `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey`. 
**When does this key exist?**

Corresponding to the key, there is some value. 
**What is in this value?**

I am given this key-value pair for a reason. **Why would I use it?**

Finally, and most importantly: **How do I use it?**

---

*ADDITIONAL INFO*

As I learn, I am making a boilerplate project.
Here is what is in it:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {
        print("application(application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)")

        if let options: [NSObject: AnyObject] = launchOptions
        {
            for option: (key: NSObject, AnyObject) in options
            {
                switch option.key
                {
                // The presence of this key indicates that the app was launched in order to open a URL. The value of this key is an NSURL object containing the URL to open.
                case UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey:
                    <#code#>
                ...
```

For future projects, I plan to replace `<#code#>` with something else to harness the functionality of key-value pair of `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey`.

Comment: I would reword that question at the end because you could really put anything there.

Comment: @TroyT -- Good point. I've edited the question into a statement, since really I've already asked the questions that I really want answered earlier in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably other reasons, but I use it to open specific files with my app.

My app saves backup files in its own format. If the user has one of those files in his device he can chose to open the file using my app. If he does that, my app is opened and this happens:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        if let url = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey] as? NSURL {
            handleBackupFile(url)
        }
        return true
}
```

Besides the usual launching of the app I call `handleBackupFile()` to, well, handle the backup file.

If my app could open more than one kind of file I'd probably check what kind of file it is there.

Edit:

Here's an actual example from my app, Leio:

[image: Copy to Leio]

When the user taps "Copy to Leio" my app opens and that code is called.

Comment: Could you clarify what it means during the user experience: Is it when they select "Open in..." and pick your app, or what? Also, how does this URL look?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this counts as off-topic: I assume your app is not called "Copy to Leio", probably just "Leio". If so, where do you have the opportunity to have that text under your app icon show "Copy to Leio" instead of "Leio"?

Comment: And the url is the url for the path of the file in a directory in the filesystem. In my example the file is saved as an attachment in a note, so the directory is probably the path of the Notes app's attachments plus the name of the file, in this case something like `notesPath/leio_04etc.lbf`

Comment: Is this the URL that is the value corresponding to `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey`?

Comment: Yes. And I didn't set that text at all because it would give me headaches with localizations, so that's the default text. You can probably change it somewhere, but now I'm not sure where, maybe when you set up what files your app can open.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108770/discussion-between-sir-jony-and-danielbmarques).